# R How to select an observation from a data frame which is False and has the min value

Tags: r

I have a data frame with three columns and i would like to select the observation that has the value FALSE in the column TEST and also has the minimum value at the Power column. I tried  `which(kolibri[ ,"TEST"] == FALSE) && which(kolibri[ , "Power"] == min(kolibri[ , "Power"]))`but no luck it returns TRUE but i want the index of the observation. My data frame is like this:

```
Variable_Name Power TEST
  A             2    true
  B             45   false
  C             33   false
  D             25   false
  E             15   true
```

in this case i want to have the index of the variable D

Comment: Several issues here. One, are you sure your TEST column is a boolean? Two, you only need one call to which, with all combinations of logical tests insite id.

Comment: I have to mention that i made a mistake and everything is at the same data frame. Fevgeis1 was incorrect. The right one is kolibri. My column TEST is character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data.frame is `df`:

```
with(df, by(Power,TEST, FUN=min)['false'])
#false 
#   25
```

If you want the full line:

```
with(df, df[Power==by(Power,TEST, FUN=min)['false'],])
#  Variable_Name Power  TEST
#4             D    25 false
```

If you want the index:

```
which.max(with(df, Power==by(Power,TEST, FUN=min)['false']))
#[1] 4
```

If you have `FALSE` and `TRUE` in your data.frame `TEST` column:

```
which.max(with(df, Power==min(Power[!TEST])))
#[1] 4
```

Comment: `i want to have the index of the variable D` - expected output is 4.

Comment: Thank you man. The third suggestion works perfectly!!!!! With the only exception that i have to change 'false' into "FALSE".

Comment: if you have boolean in the TEST column, the code is even simpler. I edited it in case.

Answer (score 1):

If TEST is not a boolean: transform it

```
kolibri$TEST <- as.logical(kolibri$TEST)
```

Then put everything in a call to which (used 25 as your other data are unavailable here)

```
   > which(kolibri$TEST == FALSE & kolibri$Power== 25)
[1] 4
```

Using OP's own example (which I cannot run on my machine), code would be:

```
which(kolibri$TEST == FALSE & kolibri$Power== min(fevgeis1$Power))
```

Comment: In OP's example, power was derived from another dataset (`fevgeis1`). I did this to obtain runnable code in my own environment.

Comment: But isn't that logical seeing the sample data (I see you've edited your question). kolibri$power has its minimum at 2 in the given example, and at that point the test is true.